# Could not validate timestamp: expired in laravel saml

Tags: php, html, laravel, saml, onelogin

i have integrated aacotroneo package to authenticate user through saml in laravel. im getting this error and not able to figure out whats really happening.

Could someone help me please ?

This is the error

**Could not validate timestamp: expired. Check system clock.Could not validate timestamp: expired. Check system clock.**

Comment: Not sure about saml but when we had a similar problem using OAuth it was because someone had set the system clock to the wrong UTC time and then used the timezone to correct the error so as this error says "check system clock"

Comment: I suggest you improve your question, add some examples, some code and make it more clear and add your source code, Have a look here => [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, for sure, about the laravel saml library.  Assuming [this](https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2) is what you're referring to, it appears to be based on the OneLogin library.

In the OneLogin library, a similar error means that the SAML assertion contains a `NotOnOrAfter` attribute:

```
<saml2:Conditions NotOnOrAfter="2021-04-27T17:00:00.0222">
  ...
</Conditions>
```

that contains a date that is in the past, compared to the server that is processing the SAML assertion.  That could either mean that the date from the other server is bad (maybe they failed to send it in UTC, per the [spec, section 2.5.1 Element](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf) ), or that the system clock of the destination server is off.